# Sending text message to phone using twilio

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twilio

I am trying to send text message to phone. Can someone tell me why my return statement is not working? If i write only string message in my return statement then it shows that message but if i use below mentioned return statement it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

namespace TwilioSendSMS.Controllers
{
    public class SMSController : TwilioController
    {
        // GET: SMS ----- outbound----
        public ActionResult SendSms()
        {

            // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
            const string accountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxx";
            const string authToken = "71xxxxxxxxxx";

            // Initialize the Twilio client
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            // make an associative array of people we know, indexed by phone number
            var people = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"+18180000000", "Kim"},
                {"+14401112222", "Raj"}
            };

            // Iterate over all our friends
            foreach (var person in people)
            {
                // Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
                MessageResource.Create(
                    from: new PhoneNumber("+15005550006"), // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
                    to: new PhoneNumber(person.Key), // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
                                                     // Message content
                    body: $"Hey {person.Value} Party is at 6PM! Don't forget to bring gift.");



            }
            //return Content($"Message has been sent!");
            return Content($"Sent message to {person.Value}");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Not working"?

Comment: Its complaining about my return statement. Its not accepting it. It says "The name person doesn't exist in the current content".

Comment: So it's that. the person is declared in the foreach block, you're trying to use it outside the foreach loop

Comment: If i put return statement inside the foreach loop then it says return statement is missing for the SendSms() method. It wont compile.

Comment: I just put one return statement in the foreach and one outside for the SendSms() method and it worked and compiled. I used my number as a TO but i didnot receive any message. Any Idea what could be the problem?

Comment: MessageResource.Create() returns a MessageResource.  If you store that return value to a local variable you should be able to inspect it and get a little more info out of there.  You should also be able to log on to Twilio website and view message history there.

Comment: I got it. Thanku. I added empty string before the foreach loop and adding all the values to the empty string to get a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working code!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

namespace TwilioSendSMS.Controllers
{
    public class SMSController : TwilioController
    {
        // GET: SMS ----- outbound----
        public ActionResult SendSms()
        {

            // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
            const string accountSid = "ACxxxxxxxxx";
            const string authToken = "71xxxxxxxxxx";

            // Initialize the Twilio client
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            // make an associative array of people we know, indexed by phone number
            var people = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"+18180000000", "Kim"},
                {"+14401112222", "Raj"}
            };

            // Iterate over all our friends
            var name ="";
            foreach (var person in people)
            {
                // Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
                MessageResource.Create(
                    from: new PhoneNumber("+15005550006"), // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
                    to: new PhoneNumber(person.Key), // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
                                                     // Message content
                    body: $"Hey {person.Value} Party is at 6PM! Don't forget to bring gift.");
              name = $"{name} {person.Value}";


            }

            return Content($"Sent message to {name}");

        }
    }
}
```